# What is the default GC used in Java 1.7 (45) on Linux

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection, jvm

Our JVM is HotSpot -64-Bit Server (mixed mode) on Linux.

Looking at the GC logs it seems that ParallelGC is the default. Why isn't CMS the default GC algo? Is it due to the lack of compaction? But that would be the case with parallelGC too.

We notice that a FullGC is not fired even when the heap reaches 75% capacity. When does a full GC fired for the default GC in java 1.7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Looking at the GC logs it seems that ParallelGC is the default.

It has been since it was added.

> Why isn't CMS the default GC algo?

ParallelGC is the fastest for throughput, lowest CPU usage and the easiest to use.

> Is it due to the lack of compaction?

That is one issue.

> But that would be the case with parallelGC too.

Not such an issue for this GC as it defragments.

> We notice that a FullGC is not fired even when the heap reaches 75% capacity. When does a full GC fired for the default GC in java 1.7?

When the JVM cannot allocate memory, even if you have CMS enabled. (Or when System.gc() triggers it to do a full collection)  CMS only fires a major collection of the tenured space when it runs.  There is no CMS for FullGC.

Comment: If I specify "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", that only impacts Tenured generation GC strategy, is that right? With CMS enabled, if FullGC is triggered, will it be Stop the world GC or would it be a parallel and allow the application threads to server the incoming requests? Assuming that we have a 4 core machine.

Comment: @Aadidasu A stop-the-world collection for CMS is serial unfortunately.  Are you using hyper threading BTW?

Comment: No HT. So irrespective of GC strategy --default-ParallelGC, or CMS-- a Full GC will always be stop-the-world GC, right?. Would G1 GC do FullGC without stop-the-world?

Comment: The only available JVM without stop-the-world is Azul's Zing. It is "completely concurrent".  It actually has pauses too, but they are around 1 ms worst case. My solution is to use the GC far less than most and thus these issue go away. Here is the GC profile of a real trading system I developed http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-avoid-garbage-collection.html